# Confusion about mitochondrial electron transport chain Complex I Wikipedia article title

Tags: enzymes, mitochondria

The Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NADH_dehydrogenase_(ubiquinone)) title for Complex I (the NADH dehydrogenase enzyme complex) is "NADH dehydrogenase (ubiquinone)". This is confusing to me because this title sounds like ubiquinone is another name for NADH dehydrogenase, but ubiquinone is in fact the Coenzym Q, which is reduced by the hydrogen transferred from NADH through Complex I. What is the reason behind this title? I mean, what is the point of having "ubiquinone" in parentheses in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the title of the article. The reason for the title was just poor writing (I agree that it seems to imply that the enzyme *is* ubiquinone) but also the fact that someone had previously tried to change the title to the accepted name tht **@xusr** has mentioned but they did so incorrectly.